# redirect_to not working in production, works fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After a new user signs up for the site they should be redirected to the deals index. This works correctly in the development environment, but it doesn't work in production (on Heroku). In production it redirects to the users index (which doesn't exist).

Here's my Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if valid_email? @user.email
      @user.save
      redirect_to deals_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please enter a valid email address"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private
    def valid_email?(email)
      valid_email_regex = /\A.+@.+\..+\z/i
      email =~ valid_email_regex
   end
end
```

Here's routes.rb:

```
root to: 'users#new'

resources :deals, only: [:index]
resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
```

Here's the results of rake routes, and RAILS_ENV=production rake routes (both the same):

```
    root      /                    users#new
   deals GET  /deals(.:format)     deals#index
   users POST /users(.:format)     users#create
new_user GET  /users/new(.:format) users#new
```

Everything works fine in development, but in production it's behaving as if the "redirect_to deals_path" line in the users controller didn't exist.

The app is using SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production, maybe that could have to do with it?

The app is in rails 3 and hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Did you run the migrations in the db?

Comment: Did you see the server logs?

Comment: Ya, I'd love to ee some of the Heroku logs, just run `heroku logs` in your terminal

Comment: Thanks for the tip on checking the server logs. The problem was that I had a before_save filter in the user model that sends a welcome email that isn't working properly. That apparently caused the controller to bail out of the create action.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was a before_save filter on the user model to send a welcome email that isn't working properly. I removed the before filter and it's working fine now. Here are the server logs for anyone who is interested:

```
2013-04-08T03:14:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for xx.xxx.xx.xxx at 2013-04-08 03:14:07 +0000
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b4ysVip3iTm8LZmeRxHX3EdX/pH7X6c6SpgF11IpQis=", "user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb (10.9ms)
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to user@example.com (54ms)
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 344ms
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:24:in `welcome_email'
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:15:in `block in <class:User>'
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `create'
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-08T03:14:08+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users host=www.xxx.com fwd="xx.xxx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=555ms status=500 bytes=0
2013-04-08T03:14:06+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```